# odoo 16: Many2one field - how to return value of another field Instead Of default 'id'

Tags: odoo, many2one

i have a following models:

1. coa_ledgers with id, acc_name, ledger_acc etc.
2. banks with id, bank_name, ledger_acc etc.

for my banks field 'ledger_acc' is Many2one to select from coa_ledgers and it should return the value of 'ledger_acc' field instead of 'id' field. ( Many2one field will display 'acc_name' column and should return 'ledger_acc' field value and NOT return id column value )

how i can achieve this? please help.

in my Model for banks i have Many2one field as below (by default this will Return 'id' field value from coa_ledgers but i want it to Return 'ledger_acc' field)

**ledger_acc = fields.Many2one('coa_ledgers', string='Ledger A/c')**

kindly help with all possible way(s).

regards

Comment: Where should it return? Can you specify that? In the view (GUI) or somewhere in code (application)?

Comment: @CZoellner thank you, as mentioned it should return in Many2one field whether it using in view or anywhere else. during my search for solution, i found somewhere that **Many2one only returns id column and we can have it through other way using dot operator like: self.fieldname.ledger_acc** ... please advise. regards

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly is meant by "return". In python code you get a "recordset" when getting a value out of a Many2one field. In views you get a "name" or if we talk about code in views (domains, attributes, etc.) than you have an ID.

Comment: @CZoellner let me try to explain (here column is field in model), **when user access a Many2one field in view for data entry, he/she sees the 'name' column, when select one and save, it stored 'id' column value in table. i am asking to not save 'id' column value but another column value, in my case it is 'ledger_acc'**. hope that clear.